# "error": "InvalidRegistration" error when trying to send downstream meassages through postman

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, postman

```
{
  "multicast_id": 7500517998248452157,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am getting this error again and again when trying to send downstream messages through Google postman .

My headers are

```
Content-Type application/json
Authorization key=AIzaSyAGnfrtPZsepdBX5UQ6-MFuvQd3JpF1s40
```

and my `RegistrationIntentService` code is

```
private static final String TAG = "RegIntentService";
private static final String[] TOPICS = {"global"};

public RegistrationIntentService() {
    super(TAG);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    try {
        // [START register_for_gcm]
        // Initially this call goes out to the network to retrieve the token, subsequent calls
        // are local.
        // R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId (the Sender ID) is typically derived from google-services.json.
        // See https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start for details on this file.
        // [START get_token]
        InstanceID instanceID = InstanceID.getInstance(this);
        String token = instanceID.getToken(getString(R.string.gcm_defaultSenderId),
                GoogleCloudMessaging.INSTANCE_ID_SCOPE, null);
        // [END get_token]
        Log.i(TAG, "GCM Registration Token: " + token);

        // TODO: Implement this method to send any registration to your app's servers.
        sendRegistrationToServer(token);

        // Subscribe to topic channels
        subscribeTopics(token);

        // You should store a boolean that indicates whether the generated token has been
        // sent to your server. If the boolean is false, send the token to your server,
        // otherwise your server should have already received the token.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, true).apply();
        // [END register_for_gcm]
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to complete token refresh", e);
        // If an exception happens while fetching the new token or updating our registration data
        // on a third-party server, this ensures that we'll attempt the update at a later time.
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(QuickstartPreferences.SENT_TOKEN_TO_SERVER, false).apply();
    }
    // Notify UI that registration has completed, so the progress indicator can be hidden.
    Intent registrationComplete = new Intent(QuickstartPreferences.REGISTRATION_COMPLETE);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(registrationComplete);
}

/**
 * Persist registration to third-party servers.
 *
 * Modify this method to associate the user's GCM registration token with any server-side account
 * maintained by your application.
 *
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    // Add custom implementation, as needed.
}

/**
 * Subscribe to any GCM topics of interest, as defined by the TOPICS constant.
 *
 * @param token GCM token
 * @throws IOException if unable to reach the GCM PubSub service
 */
// [START subscribe_topics]
private void subscribeTopics(String token) throws IOException {
    GcmPubSub pubSub = GcmPubSub.getInstance(this);
    for (String topic : TOPICS) {
        pubSub.subscribe(token, "/topics/" + topic, null);
    }
}
// [END subscribe_topics]
```

How can I fix this Please help

The file from where it gets the token ,looks like this

```
 {
  "project_info": {
"project_id": "kuwinterfest-1161",
"project_number": "413486297324",
"name": "kuwinterfest"
    },
   "client": [
     {
  "client_info": {
    "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:413486297324:android:8c55bff76e5fc52c",
    "client_id": "android:com.support.android.kuwinterfest",
    "client_type": 1,
    "android_client_info": {
      "package_name": "com.support.android.kuwinterfest"
    }
  },
  "oauth_client": [],
  "api_key": [],
  "services": {
    "analytics_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "cloud_messaging_service": {
      "status": 2,
      "apns_config": []
    },
    "appinvite_service": {
      "status": 1,
      "other_platform_oauth_client": []
    },
    "google_signin_service": {
      "status": 1
    },
    "ads_service": {
      "status": 1
    }
  }
}
   ],
   "client_info": [],
  "ARTIFACT_VERSION": "1"
 }
```

Comment: what does the token actually look like, can you add it here

Comment: [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes) recommends: Check the format of the registration token you pass to the server. Make sure it matches the registration token the client app receives from registering with GCM. Do not truncate or add additional characters.

Comment: I am getting the same error - were you able to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

If that is your actual api token, you should revoke it. It is supposed to be secret or anyone can send messages to your app with it.

Comment: This is an advice, not an answer. You could use the comments part ("add a comment").